# Iron Router, advantage of using map()?

Tags: dictionary, meteor, iron-router

In recent docs, like the Discover Meteor book and the Iron Router guide on github use `Router.route` for each route. But it's pretty common to see routes defined in `Router.map()` using `this.route`. Is there any real difference or a reason to choose one way over the other?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Router.map` is part of the pre-1.0 API. While is still works at the time of this writing, it may be deprecated in the future. I'd strongly recommend following whatever is in the current version of the [official docs](http://eventedmind.github.io/iron-router/).